# returning value from Python class results in "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Tags: python, class, dictionary

This code:

```
class Gizmo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.max_gizmo =  { "station" : "foo", "range" : "44" }

  def max_gizmo(self, filename):
    return self.max_gizmo

gizmo = Gizmo()
result = gizmo.max_gizmo('data.csv')
print("station {} range {}".format(result["station"], result["range"]))
```

results in this error:

```
$ python bar.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar.py", line 9, in <module>
    result = gizmo.max_gizmo('data.csv')
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

How should I be returning the value? I was using this idiom because it was working for me elsewhere.

Comment: Don't reuse the same name for an attribute and a method, when you do `gizmo.max_gizmo` it thinks you're trying to access the attribute (which is a dict) rather than call the method

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support this paradigm. I mean, you have already using the name `max_gizmo` as a method. But before that, you have declared it as a dictionary. You can make these changes:

```
class Gizmo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.max_gizmo =  { "station" : "foo", "range" : "44" }

  def rename_this_method(self, filename):
    return self.max_gizmo

gizmo = Gizmo()
result = gizmo.rename_this_method('data.csv')
print("station {} range {}".format(result["station"], result["range"]))
```

I hope this is clear now! Thanks.